# Strange result about the log sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working in a infinity sum and I get the strange result

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\log (2 \pi )$$
it seem as $$-2 \zeta '(0)$$ but i do not justify?

it maybe wrong it came from
$$\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)+\log (x)-\log (2)-\log (\pi )=-\log (x)$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{2}\log(1/n^2)=-\log(n)$. So your sum equals $-\sum(\log(n))=-\zeta'(0)$

Comment: It is a diverging series, so you have to tell us in which sense the LHS *equals* the RHS.

Comment: The terms of the series are $-\log n\to -\infty$ as $n\to 0$.  So, this series diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified view:

Consider the more general series
\begin{align}
S_{p} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 \, n^{p}} \, \ln\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right).
\end{align}
By using $\ln\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) = - \ln(n^{2}) = - 2 \, \ln(n)$ then
\begin{align}
S_{p} &= - \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{p}} 
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \partial_{p} \left(\frac{ 1}{n^{p}}\right) 
= \partial_{p} \left(\zeta(p)\right)
\end{align}
By letting $p \to 0$ then this leads to
$$S_{0} = \zeta^{\prime}(0) = - \frac{1}{2} \, \ln(2 \pi)$$.

---

Another view:
\begin{align}
S_{0} &= \frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(n) = - \lim_{p \to \infty} \ln\left[ \prod_{n=1}^{p} \{n\} \right] = - \lim_{p \to \infty} \left( \ln(p!) \right)
\end{align}
From here a number of approximations can be utilized to evaluate the limit.

---

For more information:

1. $\zeta^{\prime}(0)$ is equation (38) in [Zeta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html)
2. A Wallis Product derivation of $\zeta^{\prime}(0)$ is given in [Wallis Product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WallisFormula.html)

Comment: Awesome development ... except $S_0$   is a divergent series. +1 for the effort!

Comment: @Dr.MV  The series in question is divergent which does present problems all over the place. But... I intended the demonstration to be more of a "how to do" process. No matter how one tries to skirt around the issues, divergence, something always bites the rear.

Comment: @Dr.MV you can jusitfy this by analytical continuation...:)

Comment: @tired So, how does one define the series. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log n$?  It diverges.  What other interpretation can it have?

Comment: @leucippus Yes.  I suppose there might be another way of characterizing all of this.  Interesting post and nice response!

Comment: @Dr.MV in a conservative way you are absolutly right, but if one opens the definition of "sum" a little bit, one can make good sense of this kind of expressions. One way of doing so, is to attach another type of representation to the sum which indeed gives a finite value. The principle of analytic continuation is a good way to justify this in many cases. You also may like to have a look at Zeta regularisation techniques :)

Comment: @tired Yes, you are right.  We should write, therefore, that the function $f$ is defined as ... and by analytic continuation we extend it as ...

Comment: @Dr.MV exactly, otherwise the above is misleading